# python pandas create a list group by value

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby, data-munging

I have a dataframe in python:

```
    pID     sID     time 
0   2133    152414  2018-06-16
1   1721    152912  2018-06-17
2   2264    152912  2018-06-18
```

I want to create a new table with sID as the key and list of pID:

```
        pID time
152414 2133 2018-06-16
152912 1721 2018-06-17
       2264 2018-06-18
```

What is the best way to do it without iterating over all the dataframe?
 I tried:

```
df.pivot(index='sID', columns=['pID', 'time'])
```

But got:

> ValueError: all arrays must be same length

For these table of 3 rows
Thanks!

Comment: @mxmt it doesn't help:: df.set_index('sID')  returns a dataframe with 3 rows : meaning there are 2 rows with the index 152912 , and I get a KeyError. I need to have a dataframe with only two rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

f = io.StringIO('''
2133    152414  2018-06-16
1721    152912  2018-06-17
2264    152912  2018-06-18''')

df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+', header=None, names=['pID', 'sID', 'date'])
df.set_index(['sID', 'pID'])
```

---

[image: Results]

Comment: I get this table but now what i do `pIDs = df[152912]` I get `KeyError: 152912` instead of a table of 2 rows

Comment: @oren_ISP You should read Pandas manual as you have no understanding of indexing at all. Use `df.loc[152912]`

Comment: to my understanding, the difference between `df[i]` and `df.loc[i]` is that the latter support editing. Isn't this the case?